# Choosing the Best Matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, game-theory, nim-game

I am given `X` matrices of size `Ni*Mi` where `1<=N<=4 and 1<=M<=4, for all 1 <= i <= X`

The game consists of choosing any rectangle (submatrix) from one of the given `X` matrices and removing this submatrix.

For Example: we have 1 matrix of size `4x4`. Player 1 can choose a submatrix of size `4x4` (the entire matrix in this case) and remove it. Or they can choose a submatrix of `2x2` or `1x1` or `2x3` or any valid submatrix and remove it from the `4x4` matrix and we have the remaining matrix left in the game.

The player who can't make a move loses.

Which player wins?

Both Player Plays optimally.

Comment: If the first player can just remove the entire matrix, won't he or she always be the winner?

Comment: As an algorithm (just a quick idea), would you not attempt to choose the minimum operations left modular 2 to go? So your algorithm has to find the matrix to be removed, so that exactly 2 more matrixes exist in order to win the game?

Comment: @IVlad player choose one submatrix from one of the `X` matrix  and removes it, so in one move he can remove only one submatrix

Comment: So the game is played with multiple matrices, not just one?

Comment: @IVlad yes there total `X` matrix each  can have  size of `i*j`  `1<=i,j<=4`

Comment: https://discuss.codechef.com/t/cheaters-using-stackoverflow/14151

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Before maraca posted his answer about the Sprague Grundy theorem, I was trying to identify an optimal strategy for the game; I'll describe it below, maybe it can also be used to code a solution.)*

The outcome of the game is the result of whether each rectangle is removed in an odd or even number of moves. If the total number of moves is odd, player 1 wins; if it is even, player 2 wins.

Let's take a look at the possible rectangles:

[image: all 10 types of rectangles]

For all "normal" rectangles (except 2x2 and 1x1) the player who first removes part of it can decide whether it is completely removed in an odd number of moves (e.g. by removing it completely in one go) or in an even number of moves; the cells indicated in yellow show a first move which leaves the player in control.

For "thin" rectangles which are only 1 cell wide, the odd/even decision is taken immediately (by either removing the whole rectangle, or leaving 1 cell). For the other "normal" rectangles, the decision is delayed from 1 up to 3 moves, depending on the other player's actions.

The 1x1 rectangle can only be removed in one move (i.e. an odd number of moves). The 2x2 rectangle can be removed in one move, but the player cannot force an even number of moves by removing only part of it; the other player can always decide odd or even.

As you can see from the moves indicated in yellow in the images, a move which creates a symmetrical situation (e.g. dividing the 4x4 square into two 4x1 rectangles) leaves the person who created this situation in control of the outcome for this rectangle. He can e.g. force an even number of moves for this rectangle like this:

[image: force even in 4x4]

This is also true for the whole game: if a player's move results in a symmetrical situation (e.g. two identical L-shapes and four 3x1 rectangles) he can respond to the other player's moves by mirroring them, and then when there is only one rectangles greater than 1x1 left, he can choose to remove it completely or leave one cell (depending on whether the number of single cells left over is odd or even) and win the game.

So the strategy comes down to creating a symmetrical situation, and not giving the other player the opportunity to create a symmetrical situation.

*Note: a more complicated symmetry can be created by removing the center of a 3x3, 4x3 or 4x4 rectangle and creating a loop. Instead of mirroring the other player's moves, you then rotate them by 180 degrees (i.e. point-mirroring).*

A few game results based on these ideas:

- One rectangle: player 1 wins.
- Two identical rectangles: player 2 wins.
- A 1x1 and a thin rectangle: player 1 wins.
- A 1x1 and a 2x2 rectangle: player 2 wins.
- A 1x1 and a larger rectangle: player 1 wins.
- A 2x2 and a thin rectangle: player 1 wins.
- A 2x2 and a larger rectangle: player 1 wins.
- Three identical rectangles: player 1 wins.
- A 1x1, a 2x2 and any other rectangle: player 1 wins.
- An even number of identical rectangles: player 2 wins.
- An even number of identical and any other rectangle: player 1 wins.
- An odd number of identical rectangles: player 1 wins.

---

Below is an implementation of the Sprague-Grundy theorem, as explained in maraca's answer. It uses a list of pre-calculated nimbers for rectangles up to 4x4.

```js
function outcome(rectangles) {
    var n = 0, nimbers = [[1,2,3,4],[2,1,5,8],[3,5,4,7],[4,8,7,3]];
    for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
        n ^= nimbers[rectangles[i][0] - 1][rectangles[i][1] - 1];
    }
    return n > 0 ? 1 : 2;
}
document.write("Player " + outcome([[3,3],[3,4],[4,4]]) + " wins.<br>");
document.write("Player " + outcome([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]) + " wins.");
```

The nimber of any 4x4 matrix can be calculated with the algorithm below. The 4x4 matrices are represented by 16-bit patterns, e.g. 65535 is a matrix filled with ones. A list of all rectangles (possible moves), represented as bit patterns, is pre-calculated.

```js
function nimber(matrix) {
    var rect = [   1,    2,    3,    4,    6,    7,    8,   12,   14,   15,
                  16,   17,   32,   34,   48,   51,   64,   68,   96,  102,
                 112,  119,  128,  136,  192,  204,  224,  238,  240,  255,
                 256,  272,  273,  512,  544,  546,  768,  816,  819, 1024,
                1088, 1092, 1536, 1632, 1638, 1792, 1904, 1911, 2048, 2176,
                2184, 3072, 3264, 3276, 3584, 3808, 3822, 3840, 4080, 4095,
                4096, 4352, 4368, 4369, 8192, 8704, 8736, 8738,12288,13056,
               13104,13107,16384,17408,17472,17476,24576,26112,26208,26214,
               28672,30464,30576,30583,32768,34816,34944,34952,49152,52224,
               52416,52428,57344,60928,61152,61166,61440,65280,65520,65535];
    var memo = [0];                                    // nimber of empty matrix is 0
    return nim(matrix);

    function nim(current) {
        if (memo.hasOwnProperty(current)) return memo[current]; // use memoized value
        var exclude = [];                       // set of nimbers of reachable states
        for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
            if ((current & rect[i]) == rect[i]) {   // this rectangle is a valid move
                var next = current & ~rect[i];                    // remove rectangle
                exclude[nim(next)] = true;           // recurse and add nimber to set
            }
        }
        return (memo[current] = mex(exclude));                 // memoize this nimber
    }
    function mex(n) {                              // minimum excludant of nimber set
        var m = 0;
        while (n[m]) ++m;
        return m;
    }
}

document.write(nimber(65535));   // 0b1111111111111111 represents a filled 4x4 matrix
```

The list of 16-bit patterns representing the rectangles of all sizes, positions and orientations in a 4x4 matrix can be generated like this:

```js
function rectangles(width, height) {
    var rect = [], line = (1 << width) - 1;
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (var h = 1; h <= height - y; h++) {
                for (var w = 1; w <= width - x; w++) {
                    var bits = ((line >> (width - w)) << (width - x - w)) << (y * width)
                    for (var row = 1; row < h; row++) {
                        bits |= (bits << width);
                    }
                    rect.push(bits);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rect;
}
document.write(rectangles(4,4));
```

Comment: Wow you put a lot of effort into that (already upvoted). I wonder how you did those images?

Comment: @maraca I became intrigued by the method in your answer, and trying to code it is always a good way to figure out how something works. (The images are just a combination of Photoshop and too much time on my hands.)

Answer (score 5):

This problem is solved with the [Sprague Grundy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem), which says that when you xor the nimbers of the individual matrices, then the player to move only loses when the result is 0 (because any move will turn the losing position in a winning position and the other player can then turn the winning position in a losing position again and so on, it's the nature of nim-like games).

The nimbers are calculated recursively, a nimber of a matrix is the mex (minimal exclusive = the smallest non-negative integer not present in the collection) of the nimbers of all reachable states.

All 0s is 0, you don't have a valid move and therefore it is a loss (0).

Exactly one 1 is 1 because the only reachable position is 0 and mex(0) = 1.

For two ones we have to decide whether they are adjacent or not, adjacent = mex(0, 1) = 2, not adjacent = mex(1) = 0... and so on.

Example:

```
1 0 0 0     1 1 0     1 1
0 0 1 1     0 0 0     1 1
0 0 1 0     0 0 1
0 0 0 0
   =          =        =
   2    xor   3   xor  1   =   0   => player to move loses.
```

A fast implementation could look like this:

1. Calculate the nimbers for the 16 (10 with symmetries) different cases in advance and store them in an array.
2. Assign result = 0
3. result = result xor nimbers[readRowCount()][readColCount()]
4. Repeat 3. until all matrix dimensions are read
5. if result != 0 then the first player wins else the second player

Example 2: nimber calculation

```
matrix:
1 1
1 1

valid moves:
0 1*  1 0*  1 1*  1 1*  0 0   1 1+  0 0+  1 0+  0 1+
1 1   1 1   0 1   1 0   0 0   0 0   1 1   1 0   0 1
                         =
                         0 by definition

The other matrices can be grouped into 2 groups * and + because of symmetries.

Reachable positions from *:
0 1   0 1   0 0
0 1   1 0   0 1
 =     =     =
             1 = mex(0), because the only reachable position has a nimber of 0
       0 = mex(1), because the only reachable position has a nimber of 1
 2 = mex(0,1), because the reachable positions have nimbers of 0 and 1

==> the nimber for * is mex(0, 1, 2) = 3.

==> we already know now that the nimber of + is 2.

==> the nimber of the given matrix is mex(0, 2, 3) = 1.
```

Comment: Could you explain this to the uninitiated with a few practical examples?  I'm not sure this game is equivalent to Nim.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/topics/game-theory-and-grundy-numbers here is an in-depth explanation and some examples.

Comment: In this game, two identical empty rectangles are won by player 2, while an empty 3x3 plus an empty 1x1 is won by player 1.

Comment: Two identical filled rectangles are won by player 2 yes (x xor x = 0). I'm not sure about 3x3 and 1x1 because I don't know the nimber for 3x3 (if it is not 1 then it is a first player win). But 2x2 and 1x1 is also a win for the 2nd player.

Comment: I understand it to the point where I can see that this is probably the correct answer, but not much further :-)

Comment: It is something very specific that comes up often in programming contests although you just have to blindly follow the theorem and if you don't know it then you probably have to skip that contest question.

Comment: @maraca can you please explain your first point `Calculate the nimbers for the 16 (10 with symmetries) different cases in advance and store them in an array.` with few examples .. how to do that ?

Comment: @Marvel this is assuming that the matrices are always filled at the beginning. So you have to get the nimbers for 1x1, 1x2, 1x3, 1x4, 2x1, 2x2, 2x3, 2x4,... and so on. But the nimber for NxM and MxN is the same, so there are only 10 numbers that have to be calculated. The nimber of 1xM = M and Nx1 = N. The rest has to be calculated via the mex of the nimbers of the reachable positions (in 1 move).

Comment: @maraca i still don't get it how to calculate the mex can you explain with example ? what do you mean by reachable positions (in 1 move)

Comment: @maraca how to do you calculate the mex in matrix provided in answer

Comment: @Marvel it is all in the 2nd paragraph. If you want to know the nimber of a matrix then you make all valid moves and take the mex of the nimber of those matrices (but because you don't know that you have to do it recursively until you reach 0, no more moves is a loss = 0).

Comment: i added an example.

Comment: I wrote some simple javascript to calculate the nimbers: 1x1=1; 2x1=2; 3x1=3; 4x1=4; 2x2=1; 3x2=5; 4x2=8; 3x3=4; 4x3=7; 4x4=3 (with memoization this takes about half a second).